# Function to read files one by one in a directory

Tags: c, linux, file-handling

I am implementing an SMTP-sender in C which is supposed to read a file from a directory whenever it is created, process data and delete the file.

How can I implement this polling function which should keep doing this automatically?

Comment: What compiler/target platform are you using?

Comment: By »process data« you mean process the file and send the result by mail?

Comment: Hi Alex, I have been following your questions. They are really interesting. I appreciate your enthusiasm. I have one doubt. Are you doing any thing bigger with C? or Are you just practicing every task that can be done by C based on your interests. Please let me know if you do not mind. Any ways.. Good enthusiasm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple option is to run your program periodically from [cron](http://www.linuxhelp.net/guides/cron/). The program can use the Linux API call [readdir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) to iterate through a directory. It doesn't have to actively monitor the directory.

Here's a simple code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
int main()
{
   DIR* dp = opendir(".");
   struct dirent* de;
   while (de = readdir(dp))
   { 
     if (de->d_type != DT_REG) // Only print regular files
        continue;
      printf("Found file %s\n", de->d_name);
   }
   closedir(dp);
}
```

Disclaimer: For the sake of simplicity I did not include code to check or handle error conditons.

Answer (score 3):

Look into [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) and see if it will suffice for your needs.  inotify allows you to use a single file descriptor to monitor events in your target directory.  You can avoid polling by using select() and be immediately notified of any files created in the directory so that you can do your processing.

[This article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8478) has some example code.  I am sure there are other examples spread about the web.